# Multiple JQuery effects from a single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I'm new to JQuery but have some experience with HTML and CSS.
I'm trying to make a list of checkboxes on a form more interactive, I though I could put them inside a table, clicking anywhere inside each row would check the corresponding checkbox and change the row color so the user would know the selection had been made. For some of the rows I would need a toggle effect to reveal a new row where more information could be entered. I have had some success in doing these things on their own but cannot get them to work together. Please Help!

My toggle effect was simple enough

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top1").click(function(){$("#bottom1").toggle();});
    $("#top2").click(function(){$("#bottom2").toggle();});
});
```

For the click selection I used

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#row5 tr').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

Each click would add/remove the 'selected' class which I would use to change the row color. However I'm finding that the selected class only take effect if I use an anonymous function for the click event and adding the code for the extra row, breaks the function.

What am I missing, or am I doing this all wrong? Would love some guidance.

This is the HTML structure I am using

```
<table class="rowclick" id="rowclick5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cb"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" /></td>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td class="cb" id="bottom2"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" /></td>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td class="cb"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" /></td>
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share an example of your html structure?

Comment: `$(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');` is not more efficient and less readable than `$(this).find(':checkbox').trigger('click');`. It's a meaningless pseudo-optimization (especially in the context of a click handler) and I'd recommend against using it.

Comment: _"However I'm finding that the selected class only take effect if I use an anonymous function for the click event and adding the code for the extra row, breaks the function."_ -- what is the code you are adding that is breaking the function?

Comment: When I add the code to toggle a new row, it no longer selects the check box when clicking on the table row.

Comment: As I said before, the two code snippits above work separately, but I cannot get them to work together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#row5 tr', function (event) {
        var newState = !$(this).is('.selected');

        $(this)
            .toggleClass('selected', newState)
            .find(':checkbox').prop('checked', newState);
    });
});
```

This uses [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) (via `$(document).on()`) and prevents that the state of the checkbox (checked/not checked) and the state of the row (selected/not selected) ever become inconsistent.

Note that I would probably use `tr.selectable` instead of `#row5 tr`, as the latter is a bit too specific and therefore hinders re-usability.

Comment: What is the purpose of toggleClass() second parameter here? Because this is already default behaviour to toggle class. Maybe i miss something. And as a side note, if binding to `document` level, no need to wait for ready handler to be fired

Comment: @A.Wolff It [forces the state of the class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state), preventing that things become inconsistent (i.e. checked checkbox, unselected row or vice versa).

Comment: But here, `!$(this).is('.selected')` would always give the same result as just toggling the class `$(this)
            .toggleClass('selected')`  Maybe if some code somewhere else set `selected` class programatically without checking the checkbox but then this buggy code should be fixed formely

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, but out of experience there is a good chance that the `.selected` class could be set from other parts of the code as well. Being explicit about the desired state has the advantage that the UI corrects itself. When two separate UI elements need to share a consistent state then it's useful to do it that way. Call it defensive.

Comment: Indeed but i would more call it readable than defensive. Good point!

Comment: @A.Wolff "Explicit is better than implicit.", as the credo goes.

Comment: where would I add the code to toggle specific rows within the table $("#similars").click(function(){$("#similars_more").toggle();});  this should toggle the visibility of a row below similars called similars_more

Comment: @Shaz Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments that have nothing to do with your original question, this is not how StackOverflow works. If your original question is answered, close the thread and open a new one. (Asking a complete question is surprisingly hard. If you find that you keep adding details and additional sub-questions to your original problem, that's a good indicator that you haven't defined your problem yourself yet, and *that's* a good indicator that you've asked your main question too soon.)

Comment: @Tomalak I believe my original question was about getting the two code snippets working together from one click event. The answers so far have been great in expanding my knowledge of jQuery but have only delt with the toggling of the selected class not toggling the hidden row at the same time. I tried to be as clear as I could.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for your answer though, it's a much better way of implementing what I want.

Comment: @Shaz There is no mention of `#similars` (etc) in your question, so I can't see the direct relation. Anyway, it's best when you don't work with IDs, but with CSS classes and document traversal. Use elements with a `.toggleSimilar` class. In the `click` event handler for them, use jQuery's [tree traversal functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to move through the DOM and select the elements you want to toggle and toggle them - `$(this).closest("<div>").next().toggle()` or whatever, it really depends on your document structure.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the feed back, I will give that a try.
I can see where I've confused you, since posting the question I had changed the ids from #top1 / #bottom1 to #similars / #similars_more
I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: @Shaz That's all I ask. General advice: Effective jQuery code depends on a sane HTML structure, so if you find it difficult to reach the elements you want through DOM traversal, think about streamlining document structure first and about writing more complex jQuery code second. The simpler and more logical your HTML is, the more clear and readable will your JS code be.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check /uncheck it using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#row5 tr').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ($(event.target).is(':not(:checkbox)')) {
      $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('selected'));
      // if you want to trigger click handler bound to checkbox
      // without making it bubbles, use:
      /*$(':checkbox', this).triggerHandler('click');*/
    }
  });
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Downvote countered. There is no reason to dovnvote this, it's a correct solution.